# Android v7 version 19.1.0 Support Library Direct Link

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to Download the v7 app compat support library version 19.1.0. The current version of the library is 21.something. However, this requires lolipop as the compile sdk and an update to the build tool. We do not want to make these changes. Also we are using ant and not gradle. Hence, Need a direct download link to the 19.1 version of the support libraries.

Thanks

Comment: courtesy of http://mark.gg/2013/07/09/what-android-support-library-am-i-on/ 

Here is a URL to get the libs replace the XX with the revision number u want.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_rXX.zip

Answer (score 0):

These can be downloaded from the Github account.
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master

You specifically want 19.1.0 which is located here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/l-preview